# How to configure synchronous replication in AWS RDS PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

By default, RDS PostgreSQL replication is asynchronous. I have a few Elasticsearch indexing by the last modified date of records from the RDS read replica. As replicas are asynchronous I'm missing to index a few records.
I'm looking for a way to make RDS PostgreSQL replica sync synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

You might or might not be able to use synchronous_commit (see: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/warm-standby.html#SYNCHRONOUS-REPLICATION ). However, as mavink states:

"""
AWS probably uses disk-level replication instead of relying on builtin Postgres replication. Which means they effectively mirror the local disk, and making the settings "local", "on" and "remote_write" do the exact same thing.
""" - https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/ikhuyn/performance_penalty_of_multiaz_postgres_with/

I recommend asking AWS Support.